# How to Chain Service Requests Serially using Publishers

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have three functions that need to be called serially.  Two of them are publishers.  The third one creates sockets.  After calling the first function(request publisher) I need to then turn around and call other requests.

I am having a hard time with the syntax for chaining and mapping the outcome of one request to the other.

My calls in order are

```
//1
func getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: String)-\> AnyPublisher\<CredentialsResponse, Error\>
//2
func getSession(token: String) -\> AnyPublisher\<Session, Error\>
//3
func setupSockets(sessionID: String) -\> SocketManager?
```

The getCredentialsPublisher compiles and returns the expected information.

The trouble I am having is trying to convert getSession publisher to return a SocketManager.

```
func startSession(uniqueId: String) -\> AnyPublisher\<SocketManager?, Never\>
     return getSession(token: uniqueId)
         .flatMap { response in
             let socket =  self.setupSockets(sessionID: response.id)
             return  Just(socket)
             .catch { \_ in
                 Just(nil)
              }
          }
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

this gives me a "Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<P.Output, Error>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<SocketManager?, Never>'"

Any ideas why?

since sockets are created once, is it ok to have "Never" for the failure?

In my viewModel, I use it like this

```
var credentialsSubscriber: AnyCancellable?
var startSessionSubscriber: AnyCancellable?

credentialsSubscriber =.getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: object)
    .sink { result in
        print("result from get credentials: (result).")
     } receiveValue: { response in
          //A. start sockets
          startSessionSubscriber = startSession(uniqueId: response.id)
               .sink( receiveValue: { socket in  
                   self.socketManager = socket
           }
          //B. do something else that needs to be done when credentials are received.
     }
```

is this the proper way to chain calls 1 and 2?  Do I need different subscribers for A. and B.?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just about everything you're doing is backward — at least, if your description of what you want to do is accurate.

What you say you want to do is get the first publisher, use the published result from that publisher to get the second publisher, then use the published result from *that* publisher to produce a socket manager. Okay, then:

- The way to start a publisher based on the value published by a previous publisher is `flatMap`.
- The way to do something non-async (no publisher involved) based on the value published by a publisher is `sink`.

Let us take your three functions as a given; that is, let's just presume that you have such functions and that they compile:

```
func getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: String) -> AnyPublisher<CredentialsResponse, Error> {
    // ...
}

func getSession(token: String) -> AnyPublisher<Session, Error> {
    // ...
}

func setupSockets(sessionID: String) -> SocketManager? {
    // ...
}
```

So here's a toy example that compiles; all you have to do is fill in the missing part that connects each output to the next step:

```
    let pipeline = self.getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: "howdy")
        .flatMap { credentialsResponse in
            // obtain value for token here...
            let token = "heyho" // or whatever
            return self.getSession(token: token)
        }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
            // do something if error?
        }, receiveValue: { session in
            // obtain value for session ID here...
            let sessionID = "yoho" // or whatever
            if let manager = self.setupSockets(sessionID: sessionID) {
                // do something with the manager
            }
        })
```

Store that pipeline in a Set of AnyCancellable, and it will run.

Comment: this work great, had to add "-> AnyPublisher<Session, Error> " to the flatMap to get it to compile.  The other half of my question, which is after a value is received from getCredentialsPublisher,  I need to do two tasks, one was the getSession and  getInfo(also a publisher). How would I go about doing this? @matt

Comment: There is no `getInfo` in your question. I answered the question you actually asked. And in any case it would probably better to get this completely ironed out and then ask a separate question.

Comment: thanks, I'll check it as answered

Comment: Thanks - let me know what you've asked the new question so I can help with that! :)

Comment: the other half of the question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74304002/how-to-share-a-publisher-between-two-flows