# How to Share a Publisher between Two Flows

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am using one publisher, when there is a value, I need to execute two different flows also using publishers.  How do I go about sharing the results from the first publisher to accomplish both flows below.

```
//1
func getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: String)-\> AnyPublisher\<CredentialsResponse, Error\>
//A task 1  - create sockets
//B task 2  - retrieve display info from another service request publisher


For Task A 
//A1
func getSession(token: String) -\> AnyPublisher\<Session, Error\>
//A2
func setupSockets(sessionID: String) -\> SocketManager?

For Task B
//B1
func getExternalObject( token: String) -\> AnyPublisher\<Object, Error\>
//B2
func getViewInfo( Object: struct) -\> AnyPublisher\<ViewInfo, Error\>
```

I currently do this for the first task

```
    let pipeline = self.getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: "howdy")
        .flatMap { credentialsResponse -> AnyPublisher\<Session, Error\> in
            // obtain value for token here...
            let token = "heyho" // or whatever
            return self.getSession(token: token)
        }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
            // do something if error?
        }, receiveValue: { session in
            // obtain value for session ID here...
            let sessionID = "yoho" // or whatever
            if let manager = self.setupSockets(sessionID: sessionID) {
                // do something with the manager
            }
        })
```

How would I go about doing both tasks (A and B ) from the first publisher(getCredentialsPublisher)? another pipeline like this?

```
   let pipeline2 = self.getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: "howdy")
        .flatMap { credentialsResponse -> AnyPublisher\<Object, Error\> in
            // obtain value for token here...
            let token = "heyho" // or whatever
            return getExternalObject( token: String) 
        }
        .flatMap { Object ->  AnyPublisher\<ViewInfo, Error\> in
            // obtain value for object here...
            let object = “yaho” // or whatever
            return getViewInfo( Object: struct)
        }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
            // do something if error?
        }, receiveValue: { viewInfo in
            //do whatever I need to do with the view info logic
        })
```

How can trigger both flows from the first publisher value?  I don't want to call the request two times.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to combine the results of 2 publishers like `combineLatest`?. Refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/breakpoint/combinelatest(_:)

Comment: No, I need to do 1-A1-A2  and 1-B1-B2

Comment: Did you want to use async await instead? Could you read your question and rephrase it in simpler terms instead of saying "I am using one publisher to then turn", here "then" is confusing. Not even sure what precedes that.

Comment: updated the question, let me know if it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks, It is clearer now, just wondering if you must use Combine for this. I feel async await might be a better fit for this.

Answer (score 1):

Break the pipeline constructions into three stages:

1. Create the initial publisher and call `.share()` on it.
2. Create the first pipeline starting with the shared publisher.
3. Create the second pipeline starting with the shared publisher.

Here is a pure sketch; I have not made any attempt to simulate the *real* second pipeline, I'm just showing you how it fits into the topology you're describing:

```
    let initialPublisher = self.getCredentialsPublisher(userInfo: "howdy").share()

    let pipeline1 = initialPublisher
        .flatMap { credentialsResponse -> AnyPublisher<Session, Error> in
            // obtain value for token here...
            let token = "heyho" // or whatever
            return self.getSession(token: token)
        }
        .sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
            // do something if error?
        }, receiveValue: { session in
            // obtain value for session ID here...
            let sessionID = "yoho" // or whatever
            if let manager = self.setupSockets(sessionID: sessionID) {
                // do something with the manager
            }
            print("I'm the first pipeline")
        })

    let pipeline2 = initialPublisher
        .flatMap { _ in
            return Just(1)
        }.sink(receiveCompletion: {_ in
            // whatever
        }, receiveValue: { _ in
            print("I'm the second pipeline")
        })
```

If you store both pipelines in a set of AnyCancellable, the publisher will publisher and you will see that both pipelines run, and that they run in parallel, independently (so that the order of the `print` statements could be either way around).